# Which 10 words has the highest TF-IDF value in each document / total?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

**I am trying to get the words with the 10 highest TF-IDF scores for each document.**

I have a column in my dataframe that contains the preprocessed text (without punctuation, stop words, etc.) from my various documents. One row means one document in this example.

[image: my dataframe]

It has over 500 rows and I am curious about the most important words in each row.

So I ran the following code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['liststring'])
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
dense = vectors.todense()
denselist = dense.tolist()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(denselist, columns=feature_names)
```

Which gives me a TF-IDF matrix:

[image: tf idf matrix]

My question is, how can I collect the top 10 words that has the highest TF-IDF value? It would be nice to make a column in my original dataframe (df) that contains the top 10 words for each row, but also know which words are the most important in total.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minimal reproducible example for `20newsgroups` dataset is:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

X,y = fetch_20newsgroups(return_X_y = True)
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
X_tfidf = tfidf.fit_transform(X).toarray()
vocab = tfidf.vocabulary_
reverse_vocab = {v:k for k,v in vocab.items()}

feature_names = tfidf.get_feature_names()
df_tfidf = pd.DataFrame(X_tfidf, columns = feature_names)

idx = X_tfidf.argsort(axis=1)

tfidf_max10 = idx[:,-10:]

df_tfidf['top10'] = [[reverse_vocab.get(item) for item in row] for row in tfidf_max10 ]

df_tfidf['top10']

0        [this, was, funky, rac3, bricklin, tellme, umd...
1        [1qvfo9innc3s, upgrade, experiences, carson, k...
2        [heard, anybody, 160, display, willis, powerbo...
3        [joe, green, csd, iastate, jgreen, amber, p900...
4        [tom, n3p, c5owcb, expected, std, launch, jona...
                               ...                        
11309    [millie, diagnosis, headache, factory, scan, j...
11310    [plus, jiggling, screen, bodin, blank, mac, wi...
11311    [weight, ended, vertical, socket, the, westes,...
11312    [central, steven, steve, collins, bolson, hcrl...
11313    [california, kjg, 2101240, willow, jh2sc281xpm...
Name: top10, Length: 11314, dtype: object
```

To get top 10 features with highest TfIdf, please use:

```
global_top10_idx = X_tfidf.max(axis=0).argsort()[-10:]
np.asarray(feature_names)[global_top10_idx]
```

Please ask if something is not clear.

Comment: Thank you very much Sergey, I really appreciate your detailed solution! It works very well with my data, except that in the end the global top 10 words unfortunately don’t give correct results. I checked that I exported the df_tfidf['top10'] into an excel then I made a pivot and got different results but I am sure that the df_tfidf['top10'] is correct.  Looks like if it would be in alphabetical order because all of the words starts with letter 'a' in my dataset and in your 20newsgroups dataset all words are numbers.

Comment: Can you try `global_top10_idx = X_tfidf.max(axis=0).argsort()[-10:]` please?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work properly either, but I got a correct result with the following code:

`import collections

slist = []
for x in df_tfidf ['top10']:
     slist.extend (x)

counter = collections.Counter (slist)
print (counter.most_common (n = 10))`

Comment: I suspect we have different definitions of what are top10 words globally. Mine are those that have highest tfidf column wise. It's up to you to choose one you're comfortable with. In any case my original was wrong from any definition. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Do you know maybe, how can I add their tf-idf score as well? For example, as a result instead of [region, service, almost, wednesday, detect, f...], [region: 0.2, service: 0.4, almost: 0.5, wednesday: 0.6, detect: 0.7, f...]?

Comment: Great answer Sergey, thanks a lot! Do you have another solution for dealing with large datasets?

Comment: @LixingLiang What is "large"?

Comment: around 1m * 20 words. My jupyterlab will restart every time when running "idx = X_tfidf.argsort(axis=1)". It seems that my memory is not enough.

Comment: @LixingLiang Either find a more powerful machine (Google Colab, GCP, AWS, Azure) or try out of memory solution (`Spark` may do, but I am not sure).

Comment: For sentences having only stop words also it is giving top 10 words, can we avoid that?  Basically, it considered the 0 values as well while doing argsort. Can we avoid that?

Comment: @VenkateshGandi I advise you to put this as question and pin me

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov just posted it and tagged you, not sure if you got the notification sharing the link here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72971576/can-we-get-columns-names-sorted-in-the-order-of-their-tf-idf-values-if-exists