# Can we get columns names sorted in the order of their tf-idf values (if exists) for each document?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tf-idf, columnsorting, tfidfvectorizer

I'm using sklearn TfIdfVectorizer. I'm trying to get the column names in a list in the order of thier tf-idf values in decreasing order for each document? So basically, If a document has all the stop words then we don't need any column names.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

msg = ["My name is Venkatesh",
       "Trying to get the significant words for each vector",
       "I want to get the list of words name in the decresasing order of their tf-idf values for each vector",
       "is to my"]

stopwords=['is','to','my','the','for','in','of','i','their']

tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stopwords)

tfidf_matrix=tfidf_vect.fit_transform(msg)

pd.DataFrame(tfidf_matrix.toarray(), 
                 columns=tfidf_vect.get_feature_names_out())
```

[image]

I want to generate a column with the list word names in the decreasing order of their tf-idf values
So the column would be like this

```
    ['venkatesh','name']
    ['significant','trying','vector','words','each','get']
    ['decreasing','idf','list','order','tf','values','want','each','get','name','vector','words']
    [] # empty list Since the document consists only stopwords
```

Above is the primary result I'm looking for, it would be great if we get the sorted dict with tdfidf values as keys and the list of words as values asociated with that tfidf value for each document

So,the result would be like the below

```
{'0.785288':['venkatesh'],'0.619130':['name']}
{'0.47212':['significant','trying'],'0.372225':['vector','words','each','get']}
{'0.314534':['decreasing','idf','list','order','tf','values','want'],'0.247983':['each','get','name','vector','words']}
{} # empty dict Since the document consists only stopwords
```

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Can you please help?

Comment: Please full [reprex] depicting the problem and expected result

Comment: Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code does what you want and avoids using pandas:

```
from itertools import groupby

sort_func = lambda v: v[0] # sort by first value in tuple
all_dicts = []
for row in tfidf_matrix.toarray():
    sorted_vals = sorted(zip(row, tfidf_vect.get_feature_names()), key=sort_func, reverse=True)
    all_dicts.append({val:[g[1] for g in group] for val, group in groupby(sorted_vals, key=sort_func) if val != 0})
```

You could make it even less readable and put it all in a single comprehension! :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Got the required output. Even I can get the sorted list as well.

Comment: For those who are looking for a sorted list of names can consider this


`from itertools import groupby

sort_func = lambda v: v[0] # sort by first value in tuple
significant_words_ordered_list=[]
all_dicts = []
for row in tfidf_matrix.toarray():
    sorted_vals = sorted(zip(row, tfidf_vect.get_feature_names()), key=sort_func, reverse=True)
    significant_words_ordered_list.append([i[1] for i in sorted_vals if(i[0]!=0)])
    all_dicts.append({val:[g[1] for g in group] for val, group in groupby(sorted_vals, key=sort_func) if val != 0})`

Answer (score 1):

The combination of the following function and to_dict() method on dataframe can give you the desired output.

```
def ret_dict(_dict):
    # Get a list of unique values
    list_keys = list(set(_dict.values()))
    processed_dict = {key:[] for key in list_keys}
    
    # Prepare dictionary
    for key, value in _dict.items():
        processed_dict[value].append(str(key))
    
    # Sort the keys (as you want)
    sorted_keys = sorted(processed_dict, key=lambda x: x, reverse=True)
    sorted_keys = [ keys for keys in sorted_keys if keys > 0]

    # Return the dictionary with sorted keys
    sorted_dict = {k:processed_dict[k] for k in sorted_keys}

    return sorted_dict
```

Then:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_matrix.toarray(), columns=tfidf_vect.get_feature_names_out())
list_dict = res.to_dict('records')
processed_list = []

for _dict in list_dict:
    processed_list.append(ret_dict(_dict))
```

**processed_list** contains the output you desire. For instance: processed_list[1] would output:

```
{0.47212002654617047: ['significant', 'trying'], 0.3722248517590162: ['each', 'get', 'vector', 'words']}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works for me. I didn't know if we can convert the df to dict. This is the key for this. learned something new today. Thank you so much.